# From where I can download Jenkins build-pipeline-plugin?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-deployment

I am trying to find location from where I can download the latest release of Jenkins build

pipeline plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin but am

unable to do so. I checkout out the code and build it on my system but when I installed the

plugin it does not show me the view option for build pipeline. It would be helpful if you can

help me find the location of plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [download server](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org) of Jenkins. There you will find all the downloads available for both Jenkins releases as well as plugins:

http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/build-pipeline-plugin/latest/